# chained promise in for loop doesn't execute properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have chainable promises which are working fine in a single series but now i want to call this serios of chain inside for loop but it does not work as expected.

see my [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M5so23CKEJPwSdswgsRf?p=preview)  and see the output in console.

below is the structure of my chaining promises . I want all **publicIP**  which is returned by `funTwo`; but I want to complete `funThree()` and then want to get all **publicIP**. As I know that `$q.when()` makes a value in promise object.

but you can see that `console.log('pA', promiseArray);` executed very before and `console.log('res three');` and why `successHandler` and `finally` called before that?

Here surely I am missing something , may be have to write a `return;` in proper place , kindly help me how to executed all function in for loop and return a data array after that for loop ends which can be retried in `successHandler`

```
 MyService.funZero()
     .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var promiseArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
            console.log('I', i);
            MyService.funOne()
           .then(MyService.funTwo)
           .then(function(res2) {
                console.log('res two', res2);
                publicIP = res2.ip;
                console.log('i', publicIP);
                promiseArray.push({'ip': publicIP});
                return MyService.funThree(publicIP);
           })
           .then(function() {
                 console.log('res three');
           })
           } // for loop ends
        console.log('pA', promiseArray);
        return $q.when(promiseArray);
      })
      .then(function(res4){
          console.log('after for loop', res4);
      })
      .then(successHandler)
      .catch(errorHandler)
      .finally(final, notify);
```

Comment: this is not a duplicate @Phil .. I have already read this but didn't get how to apply in angularJS.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.

Comment: isnt promiseArray just an array of objects? but the name implies otherwise and you are doing a $q.when(promiseArray)

Comment: yes `promiseArray` is an array , I want to turn it into promise object using` $q.when`  so that it can be avaibale in next `.then() `? isn't it correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not sure exactly what MyService.funThree does, but you can aggregate an array via `ipArray.push({'ip': publicIP})` and return that to the `MyService.funThree` and then the subsequent function.  The issue here is there is no guarantee of order in the `ipArray` if that's what you're looking for.  Here's the middle section of that function:

```
ipArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
  console.log('I', i);
  var promise = MyService.funOne()
    .then(MyService.funTwo)
    .then(function(res2) {
      console.log('res two', res2);
      publicIP = res2.ip;
      console.log('i', publicIP);
      ipArray.push({'ip': publicIP});
      return ipArray;
    })
    .then(MyService.funThree)
    .then(function() {
      console.log('res three');
    });

  promiseArray.push(promise);
}
console.log('pA', promiseArray);
return $q.all(promiseArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input BUT in my situation `MyService.funThree()` used data  from` res2` ; so this is not possible to exceute funThree in next ` .then()`

Comment: Then instead of returning `ipArray` here, you can return `res2` and pass it as an argument to `MyService.funThree`.